# Spring MVC Java application design

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I`m creating Java web application which has users with different roles (like admin, user, visitor etc.). I am going to follow REST principles.

Now I am creating a @Controller level of my application and i don`t know should i create separate Controller for each role? I haven`t complex vision on this problem. Maybe somebody can advice me an article with design principles or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPEL` to allow users having certain roles can visit the given link.